# my animation css don't work on firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I found a code that use animation css. it works on chrome but in firefox and IE it sticks
this code create a great sky with cloud.

I shorted my code.

can somebody help me?

```
.sky {
-webkit-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
-moz-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
-o-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.clouds_one 
{
-webkit-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
-o-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
0% {left:0}
100% {left:-200%}
}
@-moz-keyframes cloud_one {
0% {left:0}
100% {left:-200%}
}
```

Comment: Most broswers no longer use a vendor prefix for animations and you haven't included a non-prefixed version...so new versions of browsers are ignoring older vendor prefixed statements.

Comment: would  you please tell me what do you mean of non-prefixed version?

Comment: If you make a brief demo of the issue, it would be simpler

Comment: look at this link [excel iran](http://project.exceliran.com)

Comment: A demo using JSFiddle or a Stack Snippet is what I meant.

Comment: aha :). sorry. here you are [JSFiddle demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1xbz10cp/). I deleted some unnecessary css codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...you had some CSS errors (missing semi-colons) which might have been the original issue **and** were missing some vendor-prefixed declarations and, I think, some *non*-prefixed versions.

Howver, for completeness, I've given the full CSS in the Stack Snippet below.

Compiled in [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BoyMON) after using [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) which I highly recommend using.

Tested in Chrome 45, FF41b & IE Edge on W10.

```css
.sky {
  height: 580px;
  background: #007fd5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
  -o-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px
}
.clouds_one {
  background: url('http://project.exceliran.com/ProjectForm/img/clouds/cloud_one.png');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  -webkit-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.clouds_two {
  background: url('http://project.exceliran.com/ProjectForm/img/clouds/cloud_two.png');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  -webkit-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
.clouds_three {
  background: url('http://project.exceliran.com/ProjectForm/img/clouds/cloud_three.png');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  -webkit-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
@-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
  0% {
    background: #007fd5;
    color: #007fd5
  }
  50% {
    background: #007fd5;
    color: #a3d9ff
  }
  100% {
    background: #007fd5;
    color: #007fd5
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moon {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -200%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 500px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
#webdesign {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
@keyframes cloud_one {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
@keyframes cloud_two {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
@keyframes cloud_three {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sky">
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <div class="clouds_one"></div>
  <div class="clouds_two"></div>
  <div class="clouds_three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @Paulie_D . it worked perfect. actually my css minifyer had problem too.